# How to create/Excecute a function that can perform an action in all components created in a specific page

Tags: angular, typescript

Iam new to angular , I dont know if you even understand what iam trying to do from my question, So here is the thing I have a component, say

```
@Component({
    selector: 'customComponent',
    templateUrl: 'Custcomponent.html',

})

export class CustomTextbox  {
    @Input() DataSource: any[];
    performValidation(){
    //Validate This component
    }   
    ClearData(){
    //Clear Data
    }
}
```

Iam Using Multiple copies of this same component in my app
like

```
    <customComponent [datasource]="data1"></customComponent>
    <customComponent [datasource]="data2"></customComponent>
    <customComponent [datasource]="data3"></customComponent>
    <customComponent [datasource]="data4"></customComponent>
<button (click)="ClearDataFromAllComponents()"></button>
<button (click)="ValidateAllComponents()"></button>
```

What can i do to perform

> `ClearData()`

and

> performValidation()

of all components in a single call , I can predict how many customComponents will be used in a page, This is an attempt to create some reusable simple components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your parent component add a member variable annotated with `ViewChildren` and as an argument set the class name of the component:

```
@ViewChildren(CustomTextbox) customComponents;
```

In your `ClearDataFromAllComponents` method now just perform the method call on all child components:

```
customComponents.forEach(x => x.ClearData());
```

Same for `ValidateAllComponents`:

```
customComponents.forEach(x => x.performValidation());
```

Comment: is der a way like we can write a service or something so that i can avoiding this code being used everywhere ??

Comment: The `@ViewChildren` variable needs to be in every component, but you can outsource the logic for clearing and validating.